# FTPS client can't talk to FTPS server since switching to java 7

Tags: java, ssl, java-7, incompatibility

**The configuration**

I'm using the `FtpsClient` from apache commons net 3.0.1 to talk to the `FtpServer` from apache ftpserver 1.0.6.

Client and server use FTPS with installed certificates on both sides. The failing code is a junit test running client and server in separate threads. The certificates are generated and put in keystores within the junit test.

**The Problem**

The communication succeeds when running with java 6. But after switching to java 7 I get the error:

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
```

**What I already tried:**

- I upgraded to apache commons net 3.3 and apache mina 2.0.7 without any change in the behaviour.
- I also removed the line

  `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024`

  from the file `java.security` inside the JDK7.
- I switched to Java 1.6.20, Java 1.6.45 (both succeeding), Java 1.7.06 and Java 1.7.45 (both failing).
- I tried to set the properties `sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation` and `sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages` to `true`

**Question**

Do you have any idea how to make the communication work with java 7?

**More info**

Here is the full output of the failing communication with java 7:

```
***
found key for : clientkey
chain [0] =   [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: 4712
             IssuerDN: CN=Test Client CA
           Start Date: Sat Dec 14 18:42:58 CET 2013
           Final Date: Sun Dec 15 18:42:58 CET 2013
            SubjectDN: CN=Test Client
           Public Key: RSA Public Key
            modulus: bc3ba4ad85d762c901a059ef55a82a1b5064a4d0f83de811a561f8ec5abf7dad4c1955434f091b3051eb37916cfbcaa293f547ed93b15e23991019ba500aee05e27d4810d56f216b685ee0f5209f77b1f500468d7e8746ffec3467f7b50004f93bc8e5a09be8871802b22d09a517ae5e543956f8475bad359391571815cb0d2d
    public exponent: 3

  Signature Algorithm: SHA256WithRSAEncryption
            Signature: 1d1e107af090afb3806a81a1252d0714568cec43
                       3ea38f8600db1fc4409f0646b8b235ecf844b610
                       ed0c8110838ca8985bbcbe0176533fe051732958
                       2b834f4292f6503d1634cb3bfdcb5c70ca3da354
                       a92bbeb2fe02484b2c176b5e830116bdf2098353
                       35c95a3114c28dc248f85ac841406f400174779e
                       d194532d922dbc2d

***
***
found key for : serverkey
chain [0] =   [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: 4712
             IssuerDN: CN=Test Server CA
           Start Date: Sat Dec 14 18:42:57 CET 2013
           Final Date: Sun Dec 15 18:42:57 CET 2013
            SubjectDN: CN=Test Server
           Public Key: RSA Public Key
            modulus: bf7993e847452df221d9b018869d635260e3764543db9df97d03a6e99fb4dba4d91a991406c6cfcf2f5ec669e3bd0bb464ccd4691108c03d6d265c66bc2adfc521225ea766137abcdaa38cea6505af0f25155bceb15eceb9dd6c25e2e393c889b5a86b4fce91fafc759ec556c9544b07a58a9335ccd89c8b4320b814bbdc3561
    public exponent: 3

  Signature Algorithm: SHA256WithRSAEncryption
            Signature: 8c75362adb73ed9797e0d11e13c73a24f715a772
                       76c8c12188a5e50cc7823ba36f4f8c3a0f6ee70d
                       6c55a1f78791c753d9820ea26bc127d87d5add17
                       5330a1015b45d5aad881b3f8e34e875622a277b1
                       4a9267ca8fade00d1dcdbc92fd50e711e59e11c1
                       e918a807479608f8f3cd475feb90c7bbc82cb15f
                       1eb119e2b899a3db

***
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Server
  Issuer:  CN=Test Server CA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1268
  Valid from Sat Dec 14 18:42:57 CET 2013 until Sun Dec 15 18:42:57 CET 2013

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Test Client CA
  Issuer:  CN=Test Client CA
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x1267
  Valid from Sat Dec 14 18:43:57 CET 2013 until Sun Dec 15 18:43:57 CET 2013

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv2Hello
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSLv3
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
X509KeyManager passed to SSLContext.init():  need an X509ExtendedKeyManager for SSLEngine use
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1370200030 bytes = { 234, 58, 111, 82, 3, 147, 102, 163, 67, 234, 5, 39, 120, 1, 72, 181, 97, 205, 100, 87, 239, 22, 237, 213, 149, 131, 180, 33 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 163
0000: 01 00 00 9F 03 01 52 AC   98 DE EA 3A 6F 52 03 93  ......R....:oR..
0010: 66 A3 43 EA 05 27 78 01   48 B5 61 CD 64 57 EF 16  f.C..'x.H.a.dW..
0020: ED D5 95 83 B4 21 00 00   38 C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0  .....!..8.....5.
0030: 05 C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  ....9.8...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0   11 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0  ..3.2...........
0050: 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0   0D 00 16 00 13 00 04 00  ................
0060: FF 01 00 00 3E 00 0A 00   34 00 32 00 17 00 01 00  ....>...4.2.....
0070: 03 00 13 00 15 00 06 00   07 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00  ................
0080: 0B 00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00   0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00  ................
0090: 02 00 12 00 04 00 05 00   14 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00  ................
00A0: 02 01 00                                           ...
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163
[Raw write]: length = 168
0000: 16 03 01 00 A3 01 00 00   9F 03 01 52 AC 98 DE EA  ...........R...[Raw read]: length = 5
.
00100000: : 163A 0 6F3 52 01 03 0 930 66 A3 A3  43         EA      0   5    27    78    01    48    B   5     6.1. . .:oR..
.f.C[Raw read]: length = 163
..0'0x00.H: 01. 00a 
002000:  9FCD 03 64 01 57 52 EF AC 16  ED  98 D5 DE 95 EA  3  83A B4 6F 21 5 002 00 03 38 93 C0  0A  . ..d.W.....R........:oR.!....8
0010.: 66. A3
0030 43: C0 EA 14 05 00 27 35 78 C0 01 05  C  480 B5 0F  61   CD00 64  5739 EF 00 16 3 8 f .CC0. 09.'x C0. 13H .a ..d.W.5....
0020.: ED. D5.9 95.8 83. B4. 21. 00. 0
00400:  00  38  C02F 0A C C00 14 04 00 C0 35 0E C0 00  33  .  .0.0..! 32. C0.8 07. C0. .1.1.5 .0
00300: 05 05 C0   0./F. .00. .3.39.2 .00. .3.8. .C0
0 050  09: C C00 13 02 00 C0 2F 0C C0 C0 04 08 C0 C0  12  .  .0.0.9 .80A. .C.0. 03. C0/ .0D. .0
00400: 0 16E  00  .3.3. 00. 32. C0. 0.7. .C0. .  1.1. .0.0. 
006005:  C000 02 13 C0 00 0C 04 C0 00  F F. .301.2 .0.0. .  .0.0. 3E. 00. 0A. 00. 
005034:  0008 32 C0  1 2. .00. 0A. C.0. .0.3.> .C.0.4 .2  
00700D:  0000 16 17 00 00 13 01  0000 03  0004 13  0  000 15  00  .0.6. 00. 07. 00. 09. . ................
.0060.: .FF.. 0.1. 00. 00
0080 : 003E 0A 00 00 0A 18 0 000 0B  00  34 0C 00  3  002 19 00 00 1 0D7 00 00 0E 01 00 00 0F    .......>......4..2...........
.0070.: 03. 00
009 130 00: 00 15 10 00 00 06 11 00 0 0  07 02 00  0900 00 12 0A    0000 04 18 00 00 05  00  1.4. .00. .0.8. . ................
.0.0.8.0.: 0B.. 00. 0C
00 00A 190 00: 00 0D 16 00 00    0E0B 00 00 0F 02 00 01 10 00 00  11      00           .   .   .   .   . .................
..
0090: 02 00 12 00 04 00 05 00   14 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00  ................
00A0: 02 01 00                                           ...
NioProcessor-3, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 163
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1370200030 bytes = { 234, 58, 111, 82, 3, 147, 102, 163, 67, 234, 5, 39, 120, 1, 72, 181, 97, 205, 100, 87, 239, 22, 237, 213, 149, 131, 180, 33 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 163
0000: 01 00 00 9F 03 01 52 AC   98 DE EA 3A 6F 52 03 93  ......R....:oR..
0010: 66 A3 43 EA 05 27 78 01   48 B5 61 CD 64 57 EF 16  f.C..'x.H.a.dW..
0020: ED D5 95 83 B4 21 00 00   38 C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0  .....!..8.....5.
0030: 05 C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  ....9.8...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0   11 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0  ..3.2...........
0050: 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0   0D 00 16 00 13 00 04 00  ................
0060: FF 01 00 00 3E 00 0A 00   34 00 32 00 17 00 01 00  ....>...4.2.....
0070: 03 00 13 00 15 00 06 00   07 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00  ................
0080: 0B 00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00   0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00  ................
0090: 02 00 12 00 04 00 05 00   14 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00  ................
00A0: 02 01 00                                           ...
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: serverkey
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1370200030 bytes = { 235, 19, 174, 10, 126, 94, 2, 53, 13, 203, 115, 119, 217, 226, 248, 251, 141, 255, 72, 117, 214, 8, 178, 182, 69, 65, 74, 111 }
Session ID:  {82, 172, 152, 222, 202, 68, 136, 188, 163, 83, 250, 80, 9, 33, 99, 223, 176, 113, 255, 245, 119, 35, 136, 114, 29, 204, 36, 7, 135, 58, 46, 58}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] =   [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: 4712
             IssuerDN: CN=Test Server CA
           Start Date: Sat Dec 14 18:42:57 CET 2013
           Final Date: Sun Dec 15 18:42:57 CET 2013
            SubjectDN: CN=Test Server
           Public Key: RSA Public Key
            modulus: bf7993e847452df221d9b018869d635260e3764543db9df97d03a6e99fb4dba4d91a991406c6cfcf2f5ec669e3bd0bb464ccd4691108c03d6d265c66bc2adfc521225ea766137abcdaa38cea6505af0f25155bceb15eceb9dd6c25e2e393c889b5a86b4fce91fafc759ec556c9544b07a58a9335ccd89c8b4320b814bbdc3561
    public exponent: 3

  Signature Algorithm: SHA256WithRSAEncryption
            Signature: 8c75362adb73ed9797e0d11e13c73a24f715a772
                       76c8c12188a5e50cc7823ba36f4f8c3a0f6ee70d
                       6c55a1f78791c753d9820ea26bc127d87d5add17
                       5330a1015b45d5aad881b3f8e34e875622a277b1
                       4a9267ca8fade00d1dcdbc92fd50e711e59e11c1
                       e918a807479608f8f3cd475feb90c7bbc82cb15f
                       1eb119e2b899a3db

***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 104116730850349228150645500726559419876454110473705724347998613959037720473709
  public y coord: 26531088832836488156715632939801149563569358316815609029138071362300859258679
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=Test Server>
<CN=Test Client CA>
*** ServerHelloDone
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 785
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 01 52 AC   98 DE EB 13 AE 0A 7E 5E  ...M..R........^
    ...
0300: 65 73 74 20 43 6C 69 65   6E 74 20 43 41 0E 00 00  est Client CA...
0310: 00                                                 .
NioProcessor-3, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 785
[Raw write]: length = 790
0000: 16 03 01 03 11 02 00 00   4D 03 01 52 AC 98 DE EB  ........M..R....
    ...
0310: 43 41 0E 00 00 00                                  CA....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 03 11                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 785
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 01 52 AC   98 DE EB 13 AE 0A 7E 5E  ...M..R........^
...
0300: 65 73 74 20 43 6C 69 65   6E 74 20 43 41 0E 00 00  est Client CA...
0310: 00                                                 .
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 785
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1370200030 bytes = { 235, 19, 174, 10, 126, 94, 2, 53, 13, 203, 115, 119, 217, 226, 248, 251, 141, 255, 72, 117, 214, 8, 178, 182, 69, 65, 74, 111 }
Session ID:  {82, 172, 152, 222, 202, 68, 136, 188, 163, 83, 250, 80, 9, 33, 99, 223, 176, 113, 255, 245, 119, 35, 136, 114, 29, 204, 36, 7, 135, 58, 46, 58}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 81
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 01 52 AC   98 DE EB 13 AE 0A 7E 5E  ...M..R........^
0010: 02 35 0D CB 73 77 D9 E2   F8 FB 8D FF 48 75 D6 08  .5..sw......Hu..
0020: B2 B6 45 41 4A 6F 20 52   AC 98 DE CA 44 88 BC A3  ..EAJo R....D...
0030: 53 FA 50 09 21 63 DF B0   71 FF F5 77 23 88 72 1D  S.P.!c..q..w#.r.
0040: CC 24 07 87 3A 2E 3A C0   14 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  .$..:.:.........
0050: 00                                                 .
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Test Server
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 134458256579882064220947016566567368624577136695715707428147091640608842041866510673093630777095713870085907129388401306119592396574283986066972630278941051105347425734712257624841831029349568388389668729188279474954100040403593251094972500714160890077269266835643135286378058696831905023827534267451981968737
  public exponent: 3
  Validity: [From: Sat Dec 14 18:42:57 CET 2013,
               To: Sun Dec 15 18:42:57 CET 2013]
  Issuer: CN=Test Server CA
  SerialNumber: [    1268]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 8C 75 36 2A DB 73 ED 97   97 E0 D1 1E 13 C7 3A 24  .u6*.s........:$
0010: F7 15 A7 72 76 C8 C1 21   88 A5 E5 0C C7 82 3B A3  ...rv..!......;.
0020: 6F 4F 8C 3A 0F 6E E7 0D   6C 55 A1 F7 87 91 C7 53  oO.:.n..lU.....S
0030: D9 82 0E A2 6B C1 27 D8   7D 5A DD 17 53 30 A1 01  ....k.'..Z..S0..
0040: 5B 45 D5 AA D8 81 B3 F8   E3 4E 87 56 22 A2 77 B1  [E.......N.V".w.
0050: 4A 92 67 CA 8F AD E0 0D   1D CD BC 92 FD 50 E7 11  J.g..........P..
0060: E5 9E 11 C1 E9 18 A8 07   47 96 08 F8 F3 CD 47 5F  ........G.....G_
0070: EB 90 C7 BB C8 2C B1 5F   1E B1 19 E2 B8 99 A3 DB  .....,._........

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 2E    [Raw read]: length = 5
     000         0   : 15    03    01    00  02....... 
                    main, called closeSocket()
                ...main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: auth type not accepted
..
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 2E                                              ..
NioProcessor-3, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
NioProcessor-3, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
NioProcessor-3, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
NioProcessor-3, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
NioProcessor-3, called closeInbound()
NioProcessor-3, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
NioProcessor-3, called closeOutbound()
NioProcessor-3, closeOutboundInternal()
NioProcessor-3, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
NioProcessor-3, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[2013-12-14 18:43:58,286 (pool-3-thread-1) org.apache.mina.filter.logging.LoggingFilter.log(LoggingFilter.java:130) WARN] EXCEPTION :
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake failed.
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:487)
    ...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1619)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1587)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1756)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1060)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:728)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.unwrapHandshake(SslHandler.java:666)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(SslHandler.java:552)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.messageReceived(SslHandler.java:351)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:468)
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was home-made.

Internally I used a TrustManager that rejected the authType "ECDHE_RSA", which is used by default with Java 7.

After adding "ECDHE_RSA" to the list of accepted authTypes the communication succeeded again.